# Security in HTTP Adapters

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I just started using IBM Worklight 5.0. I have been going through the HTTP Adapters recently and have successfully been able to Run as "Invoke Worklight Procedure". But I am stuck with the Adapter execution in the App. To my knowledge I think this is some kind of security issue where the client request to Worklight Server is unauthorized (401). Can any tell me or refer to some blog/website where there are steps to overcome this problem? 
I already got some of the websites but at this moment I am really confused on how to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution to this is to add wl_unprotected to `<procedure name="getStoriesFiltered" securityTest="**wl_unprotected**"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Go to: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started/index.html and read  Module 05.2 - Creating HTTP Adapters (PDF, 1.31MB) and Module 05.3 - Using HTTP Adapters with SOAP Services (PDF, 301KB). You can also use the Exercise and code sample (ZIP, 14.5KB).